# Random empty spaces/bars in seaborn distribution plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

GOAL: I want to make a distribution function for registered dogs' ages in 2017 in Zurich from the 'Dogs of Zurich' dataset (Kaggle) (with Python). The variable I'm working with - 'GEBURTSJAHR_HUND' -  gives the birth year for every registered dog as an int. 
I have converted it to a 'dog_age' variable (= 2017 - birth_date) and want to plot the distribution function. See image below for sorted list of group size per age.

[Size of dog age groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW3rN.png)

PROBLEM: I'm running into is the fact that my distribution function's x axis has empty spaces/bars in it. Every age is shown on the graph, but in between some of these ages are empty bars.
Example: 1 and 2 are full bars, but between them is an empty space. Between 2 and 3, there is no empty space, but between 3 and 4 there is. Seemingly random which values have white spaces between them.

[What my problematic distribution plot looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU1k1.png)

TRIED: I have previously tried three things to fix this.

1. plt.xticks(...)
   Unfortunately this only changed the aesthetics of the x axis.
2. Tried ax = sns.distplot followed by ax.xaxis ticker lines, but this did not have the expected result.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter(0))
```

3. Maybe problem is with 'dog_age' variable?
   Used the original birth_date variable, but this had the same problem.

CODE:

```
dfnew = pd.read_csv(dog17_filepath,index_col='HALTER_ID')
dfnew.dropna(subset = ["ALTER"], inplace=True)
dfnew['dog_age'] = 2017 - dfnew['GEBURTSJAHR_HUND']
b = dfnew['dog_age']

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.distplot(a=b,hist=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(b), max(b)+1, 1))
plt.xlabel('Age Dog', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Distribution of age of dogs', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

---

Thanks in advance,

Arthur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the age column is discrete: it only contains a short range of integers.  Default the histogram divides the range of values (float) into a fixed number of bins, which usually don't align well with those integers. To get an appropriate histogram, the bins needs to be set explicitly, for example having a bin bound at every half.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dfnew = pd.read_csv('hundehalter.csv')
dfnew.dropna(subset=["ALTER"], inplace=True)
dfnew['dog_age'] = 2017 - dfnew['GEBURTSJAHR_HUND']
b = dfnew['dog_age'][(dfnew['dog_age'] >= 0) & (dfnew['dog_age'] <= 25)]

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
sns.distplot(a=b, hist=True, bins=np.arange(min(b)-0.5, max(b)+1, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(b), max(b) + 1, 1))
plt.xlabel('Age Dog', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Distribution of age of dogs', fontsize=20)
plt.xlim(min(b), max(b) + 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]